# Render view as PDF on Django

Tags: django, pdf, render

I am currently trying to render an HTML+CSS DJango view to PDF, so instead of rendering the page, the HTML with the correct styling from CSS files is generated correctly.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/outputting-pdf/ ?

Comment: @Ngenator yes, but what they are doing there is generating/drawing the PDF from scratch, whereas what I want is render a HTML that is already created and formatted with CSS.

Comment: [At the bottom](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/outputting-pdf/#further-resources) there are links to other resources as well, one being http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/ which appears to be able to do what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your guide [PDF Generation With PISA in Django](http://20seven.org/journal/2008/11/11/pdf-generation-with-pisa-in-django/) and here the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/outputting-pdf/) (as mentioned by @Ngenator)